# Why can orphan removal be not executed?

Tags: java, hibernate

There is some code in a Spring Boot project (simplified for brevity) :

```
@Transactional
public void serviceMethod() {
   var child = Child.builder().value(...).build();
   var parent = parentEntityRepository.findById(5);
   child.setParent(parent);
   parent.getChildren().clear();
   parent.getChildren().add(child);
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
   @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
   private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Child {
   
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
   private Parent parent;

   // this field has UNIQUE constaint in the project's Postgres DB
   private String value;
}
```

and **child_table** has UNIQUE index on the one of its columns.
I can't understand, why it doesn't work, failing with "unique contstraint violation error".
As I read [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-knowing-flush-operations-order-matters/), Hibernate flushing order starts with *OrphanRemovalAction*, so the code above seems to be correct, but while checking Hibernate logs with generated native SQL there were not any DELETE statements issued after transaction had been commited.

Comment: can you add you entity classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [known Hibernate bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10123) describing this problem.

Currently, [the cascade executes the `INSERT` of the new entity before the `DELETE` (ophan-removal).](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/eba96d00ef26b91109991b06d5064d72abe66fe5/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/engine/internal/Cascade.java#L552)

To work around it, you may just *flush* the session once after clearing the list. This way the orphan-removal is done before also cascading a persist to a newly associated child (which triggers its insertion).

Comment: Huh, a 6 years old bug ...